# Img doesn't express on page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

[Gray part(Slider)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhsw6.jpg)
We checked after loading, and data came exactly.
We can check object's information(ImgURL,Text etc) in development mode(F12).
But it doesn't express.

Here are template code and script code.
Thanks.

```
<template>
    <div class="home-slider-container" v-if="hasResult">
        <div class="home-slider owl-carousel">
            <div class="home-slide" v-for="(banner, index) in banners">
                <div class="slide-bg owl-lazy" v-bind:data-src=banner.imgUrl></div><!-- End .slide-bg -->
                <div class="home-slide-content container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-6 col-lg-5 offset-lg-7">
                            <h4>{{banner.topText}}</h4>
                            <h1>{{banner.middleText}}</h1>
                            <h3><strong>{{banner.bottomText}}</strong></h3>
                            <a href="category.html" class="btn btn-primary">바로 가기</a>
                        </div><!-- End .col-lg-5 -->
                    </div><!-- End .row -->
                </div><!-- End .home-slide-content -->
            </div><!-- End .home-slide -->
        </div><!-- End .home-slider -->
    </div><!-- End .home-slider-container -->
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'MainHomeSlider',
        data: function () {
            return {
                banners: []
            }
        },
        computed: {
            hasResult: function () {
                return this.banners.length > 0
            }
        },
        created() {
            const baseURI = 'Server API address';
            this.$http.get(`${baseURI}/v1.0/banners`)
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result.data.result.banners)
                    console.log(typeof (result.data.result.banners))
                    this.banners = result.data.result.banners
                })
        }
    }
</script>
```

here is CSS

```
.owl-carousel {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  /* position relative and z-index fix webkit rendering fonts issue */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
  position: relative;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-Y;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* fix firefox animation glitch */
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* fix for flashing background */
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper,
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav.disabled,
.owl-carousel .owl-dots.disabled {
  display: none;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next,
.owl-carousel .owl-dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next,
.owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font: inherit;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
  display: block;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-loading {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-refresh .owl-item {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {
  touch-action: pan-y;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-grab {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: grab;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-rtl .owl-item {
  float: right;
}
```

Request API :http://www.baekdoo.ga/api/v1.0/banners

data structure : i checked Img url would be open.
{"result":
{"banners":
[{"topText":"Banner test","middleText":"Banner test","bottomText":"Banner test","imgUrl":"ImgURL"},
{"topText":"Banner test","middleText":"Banner test","bottomText":"Banner test","imgUrl":"ImgURL"}]}
,"message":"OK","status":200}

Comment: Hi there. The code block could use some editing an inline image (rather than a hyperlink) would make things easier to understand quickly.

Comment: Sorry, i edited.

Comment: If you get the content of `banner.imgUrl` and open in the browser, what happens?
if the image opens normally. Can you give an example of the data structure of  `result` from your API request and content of these two css classes `slide-bg owl-lazy`?

Comment: yep i added data structure and requestAPI

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find in your CSS how you are trying to use the `data-src`, containing the image URL, to set the div's background-image. But if you are trying to use the css's function `attr` that is not going to work.

Instead of that, I created a `:style` bind to set the image URL. You can check out [in this codepen](https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/KjEPXv).

```js
const initData = {"result":{"banners":[{"topText":"Banner test","middleText":"Banner test","bottomText":"Banner test","imgUrl":"https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/baekdoo/test/1b848efc76a047a5970a04712ca51c46.jpg"},{"topText":"Banner test","middleText":"Banner test","bottomText":"Banner test","imgUrl":"https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/baekdoo/banner1/5eabca00f6394ee99a5cf8191b1b018f.jpg"}]},"message":"OK","status":200}

new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: function () {
  return {
   banners: []
  }
 },
 computed: {
  hasResult: function () {
   return this.banners.length > 0
  }
 },
 methods: {
  imgBG: img => {
   return ({'background-image': `url('${img}')` })
  }
 },
 created() {
  // you API  code here
  this.banners = initData.result.banners
 }
});
```

```css
.slide-bg {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
}
.owl-carousel {
  // display: none;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  /* position relative and z-index fix webkit rendering fonts issue */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
  position: relative;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-Y;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* fix firefox animation glitch */
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage-outer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* fix for flashing background */
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper,
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  float: left;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav.disabled,
.owl-carousel .owl-dots.disabled {
  display: none;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next,
.owl-carousel .owl-dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-prev,
.owl-carousel .owl-nav button.owl-next,
.owl-carousel button.owl-dot {
  background: none;
  color: inherit;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 !important;
  font: inherit;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-loaded {
  display: block;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-loading {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-refresh .owl-item {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-drag .owl-item {
  touch-action: pan-y;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-grab {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: grab;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
.owl-carousel.owl-rtl .owl-item {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div class="home-slider-container" v-if="hasResult">
        <div class="home-slider owl-carousel">
            <div class="home-slide" v-for="(banner, index) in banners">
                <div class="slide-bg owl-lazy" :style=imgBG(banner.imgUrl)></div><!-- End .slide-bg -->
                <div class="home-slide-content container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-6 col-lg-5 offset-lg-7">
                            <h4>{{banner.topText}}</h4>
                            <h1>{{banner.middleText}}</h1>
                            <h3><strong>{{banner.bottomText}}</strong></h3>
                            <a href="category.html" class="btn btn-primary">바로 가기</a>
                        </div><!-- End .col-lg-5 -->
                    </div><!-- End .row -->
                </div><!-- End .home-slide-content -->
            </div><!-- End .home-slide -->
        </div><!-- End .home-slider -->
    </div><!-- End .home-slider-container -->
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for comment but it doesn't working :( I used css by <style scoped></style>. When i connect to main page, i receive object array(imgURL etc).So i used these ImgURL.

Comment: Did you check the https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/KjEPXv ? What is not working? Create a codepen with your problem, otherwise is impossible to help you.